# Сортировка объектов DTO по одному полю

Tags: java, сортировка, java-stream, dto

Требуется помощь. На сайте необходимо отсортировать товар по рейтингу и сделать лимит на количество популярного товара (популярность основана на рейтинге). Есть объект DTO с полем "рейтинг".  Есть контроллер в котором возвращаем главную страницу, а через атрибут выводим список популярных товаров с рейтингом 4.0 и выше.

Мой контроллер:

```
@GetMapping
public String getStartPage(Model model) {
    List<ItemDto> doublesList = itemMapper.listToDto(itemService.findByRating(4.0));

    doublesList.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getRating() != null)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ItemDto::getRating).reversed())
            .limit(4)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("items", doublesList);

 return "index";
```

Мой ItemDto:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class ItemDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private List<CategoryDto> categories;
    private List<ImageDto> images;
    private String description;
    private Double rating;

    private Integer count;
    private Integer discount;
    private String shopname;
}
```

Когда я в index.html обращаюсь к "items" - он игнорирует .collect и вообще не обращает внимание на работу stream, и выводит ВСЕ товары с рейтингом 4.0 и выше.

Вопрос: как отсортировать List с DTO объектами по одному полю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коллектор `Collectors.toList()` НЕ изменяет существующий список `doublesList`, а возвращает новый, который и нужно вернуть как атрибут модели.

Можно сразу отфильтровать и отсортировать этот список после его получения из маппера:

```java
public String getStartPage(Model model) {
    List<ItemDto> doublesList = itemMapper.listToDto(itemService.findByRating(4.0))
        .stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getRating() != null)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ItemDto::getRating).reversed())
        .limit(4)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // отфильтрованный и сортированный список

    model.addAttribute("items", doublesList);

    return "index";
}
```